# Accidentally deleted path variable in windows 8.1

Tags: path, environment-variables, windows-8.1

While adding a new path for java for Path in Environment Variables, I accidentally deleted every other path. How do i restore it? I'm using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same thing. **This will only work if you did it via console.** (**I did this on Windows 10, but it should work anyways for you.**) To fix it, I went go to the environment variables and found the **system** Path variable, clicked "Edit text" and copied the text. **Do not change anything there, just copy the text.** Then you can go to the console and type

> PATH=

Then paste in your PATH into there by going to the top of the prompt and right clicking, then click "Paste" After doing that, hit enter.
For example:

> PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;

Yours may be longer, like mine actually was, it it will still work. (If you deleted the variables via console and did everything right.)